# nginx fowarding 20% (spaces) instead of + in url

Tags: linux, nginx, unix, saas

I have an NGINX config that takes url's converts them with regular expression, this works fine. The issue is that while forwarding to the new atlassian instance the + from the URL is turned into %20 which in the application it self makes sense.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
pid /run/nginx/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 4000;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

http {



server {
    listen 443  ssl default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/REDACTED.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/REDACTED.key;
    location / {
        set $unencoded_args on;
        set $substitute_url '';

        if ($request_uri ~* "https:\/\/(confluence|public)\.REDACTED\.nl\/display\/(.*)\/(.*)") {
            set $unencoded_arg_substitute_url 'https://REDACTED.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=$2&title=$3';
            rewrite ^ $unencoded_arg_substitute_url redirect;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~* "https:\/\/(confluence|public)\.REDACTED\.nl\/pages\/viewpage.action\?spaceKey=(.*)&title=(.*)") {
            set $unencoded_arg_substitute_url 'https://REDACTED.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=$2&title=$3';
            set $substitute_url  $unencoded_arg_substitute_url;
            rewrite ^ $substitute_url permanent;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~* "https:\/\/confluence\.REDACTED\.nl\/pages\/viewpage.action\?pageId=(.*)") {
            set $unencoded_arg_substitute_url 'https://REDACTED.atlassian.net/l/cp/VjEHCLZv';
            rewrite ^ $unencoded_arg_substitute_url redirect;
            proxy_pass $unencoded_arg_substitute_url;
        }

        if ($substitute_url = '') {
            set $unencoded_arg_substitute_url 'https://REDACTED.atlassian.net/wiki';
            rewrite ^ $unencoded_arg_substitute_url redirect;
        }


        proxy_pass $unencoded_arg_substitute_url;
        proxy_set_header Host REDACTED.atlassian.net/wiki;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        root /var/www;
        index index.html;
        error_page 502 503 504 fallback.html;
        error_page 404  not_found.html;
        error_page 401 unauthorized.html;
        
    }
}
}
```

thiss is my code so far

Comment: Can you give an example from the access log together with what you get and what you expect from your rewrite code?

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the + character in the URL, you can use the rewrite directive with the break flag. Here's how you can modify your configuration to do this:

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/REDACTED.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/REDACTED.key;

    location / {
        set $unencoded_args on;
        set $substitute_url '';

        if ($request_uri ~* "https:\/\/(confluence|public)\.REDACTED\.nl\/display\/(.*)\/(.*)") {
            set $unencoded_arg_substitute_url 'https://REDACTED.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=$2&title=$3';
            rewrite ^ $unencoded_arg_substitute_url redirect;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~* "https:\/\/(confluence|public)\.REDACTED\.nl\/pages\/viewpage.action\?spaceKey=(.*)&title=(.*)") {
            set $unencoded_arg_substitute_url 'https://REDACTED.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=$2&title=$3';
            set $substitute_url  $unencoded_arg_substitute_url;
            rewrite ^ $substitute_url permanent;
        }

        if ($request_uri ~* "https:\/\/confluence\.REDACTED\.nl\/pages\/viewpage.action\?pageId=(.*)") {
            set $unencoded_arg_substitute_url 'https://REDACTED.atlassian.net/l/cp/VjEHCLZv';
            rewrite ^ $unencoded_arg_substitute_url redirect;
            proxy_pass $unencoded_arg_substitute_url;
        }

        if ($substitute_url = '') {
            set $unencoded_arg_substitute_url 'https://REDACTED.atlassian.net/wiki';
            rewrite ^ $unencoded_arg_substitute_url break;  
            return 301 $unencoded_arg_substitute_url;  
        }

        proxy_pass $unencoded_arg_substitute_url;
        proxy_set_header Host REDACTED.atlassian.net/wiki;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        root /var/www;
        index index.html;
        error_page 502 503 504 fallback.html;
        error_page 404  not_found.html;
        error_page 401 unauthorized.html;
    }
}
```

By adding the **break** flag to the **rewrite** directive in the "if ($substitute_url = '')" block, you should be able to preserve the + character in the URL. The subsequent return 301 line performs the redirect with the + character preserved.
I hope this works for you.